# How can a client call Spring Data Rest endpoints?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have Spring Boot web application with a UI built using HTML / CSS / JavaScript. I have another Spring Boot application that exposes Spring Data Rest endpoints. Both applications are registered with an Eureka service registry.

I want the UI application to call one of the rest endpoints of the other application. It will use the data to populate a drop down box on an HTML page. To do this, I'm trying to have the JavaScript directly call the REST API via [Traverson](https://github.com/traverson/traverson-hal):

```
traverson.registerMediaType(TraversonJsonHalAdapter.mediaType, 
         TraversonJsonHalAdapter);

traverson
        .from("http://spring-data-rest-server:8081/api/cars")
        .jsonHal()
        .newRequest()
        .follow(list)
        .getResource(...
```

There are two problems with this approach:

1. The UI gets a 403 stating `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`
2. The URL is hardcoded rather than looked up from the service registry.

How can I have Traverson call the Spring Data Rest `cars` endpoint without hardcoding the URL and avoiding the 403?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) 403 issue

According to [spring data rest doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#representations), you can either configure CORS on repository interface

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.example",
  methods = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.DELETE },
  maxAge = 3600)
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

or repository rest controller

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class PersonController {

  @CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
  @RequestMapping(path = "/people/xml/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
  public Person retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
    // …
  }
}
```

or global

```java
@Component
public class SpringDataRestCustomization implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {

    cors.addMapping("/person/**")
      .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.example")
      .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
      .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
      .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
      .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
  }
}
```

## 2. Hardcoded URL issue

2.1. get the host and port from service registry. The path fragment `/api` may be hardcoded or set in the service registry side because it's a convention set by you.

2.2. Traverson calls `http://host:port/api`, then you should have a response body

```json
{ 
  "_links" : {
    "cars" : {
      "href" : "http://spring-data-rest-server:8081/api/cars"
    }
  }
}
```

get `href` from the `cars` link

Comment: Thanks. In 2.1, how do you suggest the JavaScript code would get the host and port from the service registry using JavaScript?

Comment: It depends on what service registry you use. Google `javascript` + `that service registry name` should find the javascript library

Comment: OK. I use Eureka. I did a Google search but everything is about NodeJS. I'm not using NodeJS and I don't want to register my JavaScript client as a Eureka service. I just want to lookup the URL to the Spring Data Rest server. I don't know how to do that. Perhaps, I just need to write another Spring controller on the UI application that return the URL to the Spring Data Rest server.